# Error transferring ERC20 tokens from a contract to an user account

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I am calling a method in smart contract, which transfers tokens from sender account to holder account.
the transferFrom is failing with error

> MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":3714284134436,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0xf88f108502540be400832191c09459d3631c86bbe35ef041872d502f218a39fba15080a47547c7a300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018602c909e5519ba010b173df9bdb6747b6cdf6dd8f50513d0582c67d8689aaadb9645dcc8c3bcd34a020da92f1f07c57979bf1deee5dd80c7418eda23950bdc089223f1a647101bb64"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert {code: -32603, message: "Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {…VM Exception while processing transaction: revert"}

[image]

SmartcontractCode

```
function getTokens (uint _level) public onlyUnlocked {
require (token.transferFrom(msg.sender, tokenAddress, reward.stakedAmount));
//require (token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), reward.Amount));    }
```

Any suggestions please how to fix or debug issue

Comment: Did the account with the tokens `approve` the contract first?

Comment: If that's not it, you'll probably need to share the smart contract code.

Comment: I actually tried approve, but it didnt work.
I have an UI, from UI, i  called the token.approve() in token contract
Then I am calling the getTokens() in another contract(code pasted above).
Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: I imagine that `onlyUnlocked` does a `require`. That means you have two `require` statements, and one of them is causing the `revert`. Remove one and see what happens to figure out which it is. Then continue debugging. (If it's `onlyUnlocked`, look at that code. If it's `token.transferFrom`, double check what `token` is and how `tokenFrom` is implemented. Check that the allowance for `msg.sender` is at least `reward.stakedAmount`.)

Comment: And generally the sender needs to approve on the ERC20 Token and then the receiver can call transferFrom on the same Token afterwards. The sender approves the transfer to the receiver before the receiver “withdraws” from the sender.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong.
The user will call     `token.approve(Address_to_send, Tokens)`
Then the user can call another contract which contains `getTokens()` method .
`getTokens()` will call
`token.transferFrom(msg.sender,Address_to_send, tokens)`.

Is this correct?
can the `Address_to_send` be wallet address instead of contract address?

Comment: Correct. The address passed has to be the address that's going to do the transferring (in this case, the contract address).